# Change orientation of rows and columns of Vaadin Grid

Tags: java, gridview, vaadin, vaadin7

How do I rotate or change orientation of rows and columns in the new [Grid](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.grid.html) widget in Vaadin 7?

My requirements are such that I need to change both. a) header-rows and b) cells content. In this [image](http://2011.igem.org/wiki/images/a/ab/20110812_Table.JPG), there are twelve columns (1-12) and eight rows (A-H), so I've to change the orientation of twelve columns into eight rows and eight rows into twelve columns and all its cell content as well.

Comment: do want to have the row-headers from up to down instead of left to right? or do you want to change just the cell content? please provide an example and the code with the things you have tried so far.

Comment: Can we change the row header caption? For example, we can change the column caption by doing simply, `grid.getColumn("id").setHeaderCaption("X");` ... ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Vaadin 7 does not have such feature implemented in new Grid. However, one can manually rotate the items within container to change orientation.